# Move an image using a spritesheet in an if statement

Tags: animation, if-statement, lua, coronasdk

I have a beaver that is meant to follow the user `frog`. It moves in the direction of the frog at a slower pace. However I want the beaver to have a left and right animation. So I have the movement working, just not the animation.

```
local BidoofSheetData = 
{   
    width = 32,
    height = 48,
    numFrames = 8,
    sheetContentWidth = 128,
    sheetcontentheight = 96
}

--Set File Actual size
bidoofSheet = graphics.newImageSheet ("BidoofSpriteSheet.png", BidoofSheetData)

--Set the sequences
local bidoofsequenceData = {
    {name = "bstop", start = 1, count = 1, time = 300},
    {name = "bleft", start = 2, count = 3, time = 300},
    {name = "bright", start = 5, count = 3, time = 300} 
}

--frog mask
local physicsData = (require "bidoofdefs").physicsData(1.0)

--Link sheet data to previous settings
beaver = display.newSprite(bidoofSheet, bidoofsequenceData)
beaver.x = display.contentWidth/2
beaver.y = 284
physics.addBody( beaver, "static")
beaver.isFixedRotation = true

--
function moveBeaver ()
    if frog.x > beaver.x then
        beaver.x = beaver.x + 0.5
    elseif frog.x < beaver.x then
        beaver.x = beaver.x - 0.5
    elseif frog.x == beaver.x then
        beaver.x = beaver.x
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveBeaver)
```

I've tried to add it in the `moveBeaver` function, but it doesn't work.

EDIT:
i tried adding `beaver:setSequence("bleft");beaver:play()` into the different areas. it played one frame for left and one for right if you move in the respective directions. if you move to far left or right and stopped, it would play both left and right frames constantly.

but it didn't play the 3 frame animation i want it to.

Comment: You said you tried to add it into the `moveBeaver` function, and it didn't work. What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I noticed an inconsistency in your sheet data.

```
local BidoofSheetData = 
{   
    width = 32,
    height = 48,
    numFrames = 8,
    sheetContentWidth = 128,
    sheetcontentheight = 96 -- Shouldn't this be sheetContentHeight ?
}
```

I'm not sure if having the proper capitalization of `sheetContentHeight` matters, but I thought I'd bring it up. I think I know what the issue is with your animation now. You were setting it to play any time the beaver needed to move, which would reset it to the first frame of the animation.

Try this instead:

```
function updateAnim(who, seq)
    if who.sequence == seq then
        -- We're already animating the way we need to be.
        return
    end

    who:setSequence(seq)
    who:play()
end

function moveBeaver()
    -- Get the distance from beaver to frog's position.
    local d = frog.x - beaver.x

    -- This will allow the beaver to stop precisely on the frog's position,
    -- without exceeding a distance of +/- 0.5 per move.
    if d == 0 then
        updateAnim(beaver, "bstop")
    elseif d > 0 then
        beaver.x = beaver.x + math.min(d, 0.5)
        updateAnim(beaver, "bright")
    else
        beaver.x = beaver.x + math.max(d, -0.5)
        updateAnim(beaver, "bleft")
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you it works!! however if i move to the left (or right) and stop. once the beaver has reached the same x coordinate as the frog. its play both left and right sequences at the same time.

Comment: sorry im still quite new to all this. i don't understand want you mean by that. EDIT: if i move a little bit to the right or left it plays the stop sequences but in a move more then ~100 pixels then it doesn't play the stop sequence but both left and right.

Comment: sorry no it doesnt, i changed the spritesheet to the correct size. i think is as something to do the the if statement and the fact that if running the first to ifs one after the other. but i dont know i would fix it. EDIT: its like frog.x cant equal beaver.x if you move too far out